# MongoDB return child array with last item only

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 3 level nested array. I am trying an  aggregation where I get only Extras that has any quotation (not empty).

The return must have only the last Quotation... If an Extra has 20 quotations, the return should be only the the array with one item (20th one).

I am trying the $slice function but is not working... what should I use?

In this example, should return only the item _id:1 with QuotationHistory with only one item inside (the last one)

I am using $slice or $lastN with no sucess. Should I unwind 3x to the level of the quotation and addFileds with another name using $slice?

Or should I user filter inside the array on the first stage and than do the other operations?

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9sSvDZblyD9)

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    Extras: [
      {
        Name: "NO",
        QuotationHistory: []
      },
      {
        Name: "NO",
        QuotationHistory: null
      },
      {
        Name: "NO",
        NOQuotationHistory: true
      },
      {
        Name: "OK",
        QuotationHistory: [
          {
            Date: "2023-01-01",
            Items: [
              {
                Name: "ERROR",
                Price: 90
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            Date: "2023-01-02",
            Items: [
              {
                Name: "LAST 200",
                Price: 200
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    Extras: [
      {
        Name: "OK",
        QuotationHistory: [
          {
            Date: "2023-01-01",
            Items: [
              {
                Name: "ERROR",
                Price: 90
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            Date: "2023-01-02",
            Items: [
              {
                Name: "LAST 100",
                Price: 100
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        Name: "OK",
        QuotationHistory: [
          {
            Date: "2023-01-01",
            Items: [
              {
                Name: "ERROR",
                Price: 100
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            Date: "2023-01-02",
            Items: [
              {
                Name: "LAST 300",
                Price: 300
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    Extras: [
      {
        Name: "OK",
        QuotationHistory: [
          {
            Date: "2023-01-01",
            Items: [
              {
                Name: "ERROR",
                Price: 90
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            Date: "2023-01-02",
            Items: [
              {
                Name: "LAST 500",
                Price: 500
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 5,
    Extras: [
      {
        Name: "NO",
        QuotationHistory: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 6,
    Extras: []
  },
  {
    _id: 7,
    WithNoExtrasProp: true
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `$filter` out `Extras` with no quotation history(i.e. `$size` is 0). Then, `$match` with non-empty `Extras`. Finally, use `$mergeObjects` with `$last` to update the `Extras.QuotationHistory` to its last entry.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $ne: [
              {
                $ifNull: [
                  "$Extras",
                  []
                ]
              },
              []
            ]
          },
          {
            $ne: [
              {
                $ifNull: [
                  "$Extras.QuotationHistory",
                  [
                    []
                  ]
                ]
              },
              [
                []
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      Extras: {
        QuotationHistory: {
          $last: {
            $last: "$Extras.QuotationHistory"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PsXM9by6qkL)

Comment: thanks for te reponse, but is not working. My example was missing empty and nulls quotations and multiple extras... see here the full example with your query. https://mongoplayground.net/p/0DRVwcggAyB . The problems that I found here: 1) in _id:1 is not returning the correct quoatation, should had return only the extra with quotation and returned all extras and none with quotations. 2) _id:2 returned 2 extras with quotations, but the quotation was the same with both and should be different

Comment: @2Fast4YouBR updated the answer to use more array processing techinques